# How do I rereference excluded JAR in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

My project depends on two JARs. A1 and B1. A1 depends on A2, and A2 depends on a JAR named Tar.jar. In the pom.xml file of A1, Tar.jar is excluded by using the  tag.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>A2</artifactId>
        <version>xxx</version>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>Tar</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

B1 depends on B2, B2 depends on B3, and B3 depends on Tar.jar.
Then I found that in my project, the dependency on Tar.jar disappeared, and because B3 depended on Tar.jar, my project would not work properly.

I also found that Tar.jar disappears from my project dependency only when the B-to-Tar.jar dependency path depth is greater than the A-to-Tar.jar dependency path depth.

What can I do to make my project dependent on Tar.jar? I don't want to write Tar.jar directly into the dependency tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `<dependency>`. It may also be possible to do it with `<dependencyManagement>`.